# self-comparison error on attempting to compile Linphone on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, c, compilation, warnings, linphone

I'm attempting to compile Linphone on Ubuntu 16.04. When I try to do this, I encounter the following error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target bellesip
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/user/linphone-desktop/WORK/Build/bellesip'
make[6]: Entering directory '/home/user/linphone-desktop/WORK/Build/bellesip'
[  4%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/auth_event.c.o
[  6%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/auth_helper.c.o
[  7%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/belle_sdp_impl.c.o
[  9%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/belle_sip_dict.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/belle_sip_headers_impl.c.o
[ 12%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/belle_sip_loop.c.o
[ 13%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/belle_sip_object.c.o
[ 15%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/belle_sip_parameters.c.o
[ 16%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/belle_sip_resolver.c.o
[ 18%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/belle_sip_uri_impl.c.o
/home/user/linphone-desktop/submodules/belle-sip/src/belle_sip_uri_impl.c: In function ‘belle_sip_uri_equals’:
/home/user/linphone-desktop/submodules/belle-sip/src/belle_sip_uri_impl.c:304:25: error: self-comparison always evaluates to false [-Werror=tautological-compare]
  } else if (uri_a->user != uri_a->user) {
                         ^~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/build.make:304: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/belle_sip_uri_impl.c.o' failed
make[6]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/belle_sip_uri_impl.c.o] Error 1
make[6]: Leaving directory '/home/user/linphone-desktop/WORK/Build/bellesip'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:103: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/all' failed
make[5]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/bellesip.dir/all] Error 2
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/user/linphone-desktop/WORK/Build/bellesip'
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/user/linphone-desktop/WORK/Build/bellesip'
CMakeFiles/EP_bellesip.dir/build.make:116: recipe for target '/home/user/linphone-desktop/WORK/Stamp/EP_bellesip/EP_bellesip-build' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/user/linphone-desktop/WORK/Stamp/EP_bellesip/EP_bellesip-build] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/user/linphone-desktop/WORK/cmake'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:894: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/EP_bellesip.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/EP_bellesip.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/user/linphone-desktop/WORK/cmake'
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/linphone-desktop/WORK/cmake'
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

As I understand it, this error is arising because warnings are being treated as errors, so the compilation is halted by a warning. If this is the case, how can I prevent warnings from being treated as errors by Linphone? Otherwise, how can I get Linphone to compile?

The procedure I have right now for compiling is as follows:

```
sudo apt-get -y install \
                        git                    \
                        build-essential        \
                        automake               \
                        autoconf               \
                        libtool                \
                        intltool               \
                        libgtk2.0-dev          \
                        libspeexdsp-dev        \
                        libavcodec-dev         \
                        libswscale-dev         \
                        libx11-dev             \
                        libxv-dev              \
                        libgl1-mesa-dev        \
                        libreadline-dev        \
                        libgsm1-dev            \
                        libtheora-dev          \
                        libsqlite3-dev         \
                        libupnp-dev            \
                        libsrtp-dev            \
                        open-vm-tools          \
                        open-vm-tools-dev      \
                        cmak*                  \
                        libmbedtls-dev         \
                        libmbedtls-doc         \
                        libmbedtls10           \
                        libcunit1              \
                        libcunit1-dev          \
                        libantlr3c-dev         \
                        libantlr3-runtime-java \
                        antlr3                 \
                        libortp-dev            \
                        libortp9               \
                        libmediastreamer-base3 \
                        libmediastreamer-dev   \
                        extra-cmake-modules    \
                        yasm

git clone https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-desktop.git
cd linphone-desktop
git submodule sync && git submodule update --init --recursive
./prepare.py
make
```

Comment: `cc1: all warnings being treated as errors`: try removing the flag `-Werror` from the compilation

Comment: @AlterMann: Bad advice, as this apparently **is** an error.

Comment: @Olaf `if (uri_a->user != uri_a->user)` doesn't seems an error, is a NO-OP

Comment: No, the error arises because there **is** an error in the code. It is just the compiler normally flags most errors as well as flaws as warnings, not errors. So, resolve the error, don't just silence it.

Comment: @AlterMann: Yes and it is useless. Thus it likely is an error in the program logic. Maybe some regression from an (automatic) edit

Comment: @Olaf a NO-OP **is not** an error, the error arises because `-Werror` treats warnings as errors.

Comment: @AlterMann: I intentionally wrote "Thus it likely is an error in the program logic". Because there is no reasonable reason to use it. Typically such artefact can occur during (semi)automatic overhaul.

Comment: @Olaf, ah, ok, I didn't understand you and I agree, there is no reason to use it, I have founded the code and it is very suspicious: https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/belle-sip/blob/master/src/belle_sip_uri_impl.c , perhaps the intention was `} else if (uri_a->user != uri_b->user) {` instead of `} else if (uri_a->user != uri_a->user) {`

Comment: Thank you both for considering this and taking a look at the root cause of the problem. I don't have time to address odd code in Linphone (and they have disabled the ability to raise issues on it on GitHub). What I'm looking to do is modify the compile process to prevent it from interpreting warnings as errors so that I can get the thing to compile (warning code and all). Would you have any idea how to do this?